# How to determine Anaconda is fully installed on Mac?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

When I type "python" into a terminal, I get this:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I am unsure whether this means Ananconda has been successfully installed?

Comment: OS X comes with python, so you'll get that or something similar without installing anything. Does anaconda tell you where it's installing a python binary, and is that location before /usr/bin/ in $PATH?

Comment: I installed from here (http://continuum.io/downloads), and chose for Mac 10.5 or higher (Mac OS X (10.5 or higher - bash installer) 64-bit / 228M / md5: 9fd7dd485c5f04fb65699a290e69671c). AFter download, all I get is a file in my Downloads called Anaconda-1.9.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh.

Comment: The instructions for installation at the top of the download website say to double-click on the .pkg file and follow the instructions on screen, but I do not see the .pkg file (after downlaoding twice)...

Comment: Did you actually run the shell script that gives you? Unless you did something specific to get 2.6, what you're running in the question isn't what anaconda should install, which is Python 2.7. (The PKG installer is for OS X 10.7 or higher, which isn't the one you say you downloaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the Anaconda-1.9.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh, open Terminal and run

```
/bin/bash Anaconda-1.9.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
```

The installer will ask a series of questions and install it in a prefix you determine. When you are done, close the Terminal and open it again. (This is so that your Terminal picks up the new PATH which points to the prefix/bin.)

When it is installed you should see something like the following in the Terminal:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:09)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```